# iphone sdk: how to add event to UIButton added in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios5

i've a button in webview without setting event handler.how to set eventhandler for it and how to call this function in javascript and how to bring javascript value to objective c. plz give me some suggesstions.

Answer (score 0):

Add handler:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(SOME SEL) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Returning value:

```
NSString * returnValue = [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"SOME JAVASCRIPT"];
```